# moving multiple files to different directory on FTP webserver

Tags: command-line, ftp, webserver, database

So i have this webserver with a folder of approx. 7000+ files/images/documents.
I want to move around 2000 specific images to a different folder.

I think i can use SQL to get the image names from those 7000 however those would only be filenames.

So is there an easy way to move those specific files to a different folder on the FTP server?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by 2000 specific files? do they have some kind of a pattern like a prefix, or do you have the filenames of these 2000 files in a list? Or do all 2000 files have the same extension? Also are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: What are you using to access this FTP server? The Windows FTP command line tool or something else?

Comment: @SimonS well, it simply means 2000 specific files. they are all images if you want to know that but they don't all have the same extension. And yes, i do have all the filenames and the extensions with it if that helps.

Comment: @RicardoBohner uhm right now WinSCP? I also have FileZilla or maybe PuTTY? i don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: @user10515430 to give you my suggestion for a solution i need to know how you "have" these filenames. are they in a textfile? where are these 2000 filenames stored

Comment: @SimonS Oh so that's what you're asking. They're stored in a folder on an FTP webserver. the filenames are stored in a DB table. PS: I'm on Windows